# Near Field Optical Microscope

Tags: optics, microscopy

As a handyman, once I took pictures of a corner of a parfaim bottle by my camera (Near Field Optical Microscope), I'd like to know the interpretation of the following image:[image]

less powerful zoom:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cDEm2Rq1E7Y

Comment: If it is a photograph taken with a conventional camera then the image is out of focus.  What do you see when you look at the perfume bottle with your eye very close to it?

Comment: Farcher : I can see what I photographed and more provided the surface has a curvature and....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like light being refracted through the contents of the bottle, possibly with additional colour fringes due to [chromatic aberration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration) in the microscope's optics. But its impossible to say for sure without being given much more information about the subject of the picture, the lighting conditions and the construction and settings of the microscope.

Comment: I only used the camera (its lens is almost glued to the glass surface), that's why I said near field, I'll try to give more details.

Comment: I added a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MK6vnIShWJY